# Changing link href and triggering it with Javascript when its child (span) is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, pjax

I am using Pjax my mvc application like below

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#pjaxContainer');
```

I have a kendo grid that has a custom command which will open details page of the row entry

```
 command.Custom("Details").Text("<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>").Click("ProductDetailView")); });
```

and it looks like this

[image]

javascript funcion :

```
function ProductDetailView(e)
{
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));
    var PK = dataItem.PKProduct;
    e.target.href = "/Product/Details/" + PK;
}
```

the problem is when I click the link EXACTLY on the pencil icon it only adds # to url and nothing happens, but when I click green space it works correctly.
I need to somehow trigger pjax request on click of the link.

and this is the rendered HTML of table row

```
    <tr data-uid="c3ddb2d3-5847-4cf7-b892-e2ce49d1db38" role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Details Maintenance" href="#">
          <span class=" "></span>
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td role="gridcell">2</td>
      <td role="gridcell">Brandie</td>
      <td role="gridcell">3</td><td role="gridcell">British Product</td>
      <td data-value-primitive="True" role="gridcell"></td><td role="gridcell">No</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Can you show rendered html that produced from your kendo grid?

Comment: @teovankot I edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find exact solution for this, but I found another way to do it.
Instead of using Custom command I used column template as below:

```
        Columns.Template(x => { }).ClientTemplate(
            "<a  class='k-button' href='" +
                Url.Action("Details", "Product") +
                "?id=#= PKProduct #'" +
            "><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></a>"
        ).Hidden(false).Width(100);
```

and it worked like a charm.